# Lubuntu 12.04 right Alt to change keyboard layout while pressed - a bug?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

After setting the keyboard layouts and switching with this command

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:lwin_toggle,grp_led:scroll us,it
```

everything works fine (2 layouts `us` and `it`, toggle between them with left super key) but when I have us layout and keep pressed the right Alt the layout switches to it until I release it, anyone knows why it is like this and how to fix?

UPDATE:

I realize that the option "grp:switch" caused the problem. The correct command is

```
setxkbmap -option grp:lwin_toggle us,it
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in the terminal, but if you right click on your keyboard layout  icon, or go to settings. there is a setting that says "switch while alt is pressed"  maybe you have that toggled instead of what you want.

Settings > keyboard Layout > Options > Key(s) to change Layout

Comment: I think you are talking about Unity (ubuntu), I'm using LXDE (Lubuntu) so I don't have this graphical interface and just set the options from command line